# ODE of HJB function

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization

I want to solve the following ODE where W is a function of x. Any suggestion? Thank you!

```
4 m \[Rho] x W[x] + 2 \[Delta] (x^2 - 5) D[W[x], x] == 
 x (\[Beta] q + \[Alpha] x) ((k D[W[x], x])/(2 x) + m)^2
```

$$ 4 m \rho  x W(x)+2 \delta  \left(x^2-5\right) W'(x)=x (\beta  q+\alpha  x) \left(\frac{k W'(x)}{2 x}+m\right)^2$$

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code about your ODE.